# flask: how to architect an POST endpoint that interfaces with HTML dropdowns

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

So I have a sqlite db file that I've used a python script to generate that I am reading in to present information to a Flask endpoint.

The endpoint parses items from the db and generates a dict object that I subsequently pass to a Jinja template:

```
@app.route('/endpoint', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def someFunction:
    << generate finalDict via db queries >>
    return render_template('whatever.html', **"finalDict": finalDict})
```

`whatever.html` then renders a bootstrap table, i.e.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>
         Header 1
      </th>
      ...
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        {{ finalDict['someitem'] }}
     </td>
     ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

So far, so good, everything renders how I'm hoping it might.

What I want to do, is to have a final column in my table that will contain a dropdown menu that will allow a user to categorize an item in that row.

So if the row looks like `ID | name | whatever` , it will have a final `| [dropdown]` that will allow a user to select a categorization, which will always be one of three possibilities.

What I really want to know how to do is to structure the HTML and, presumably, a `if request.method == 'POST':` catch in the endpoint to update the database as appropriate.

Is it possible to treat the entire table as a `form` object and then parse through it after a user clicks a submit button using the above catch?

If not, what's the best way to structure things, given what I'm looking to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I really want to know how to do is to structure the HTML

You'll want to have a simple HTML select with your 3 options:

```
<form name="category_form" id="category_form" action="/endpoint">
    <select name='category' id='category'>
        <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
        <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
        <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Then use ajax to POST to your endpoint when the dropdown is selected. E.g., using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var form = $('#category_form');

    form.find('#category').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                //optionally do something
            }
        });
    });
});
```

> presumably, a if request.method == 'POST': catch in the endpoint to update the database as appropriate.

That's exactly how you do it :-)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.form
    #do something with data
```

`data` will be the data from the form that you submitted to the endpoint.

[Check out the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object) on the request object and how to use it.

Comment: ok, that's *really* helpful, thanks. will the above also work if I want to gather a series of filled-out dropdowns at the same time, i.e. if somebody were to fill out the dropdown on every single one of the rows? or is this set up so that each time a user uses the dropdown, it will trigger a POST request designed to handle that specific instance?

Comment: Doing it this way will send an individual POST request to your Flask app every time a user changes the value of a drop down. If you want to submit more than one drop down at once, they just need to be in the same form (with different names) then they'll be submitted together and accessible inside `request.form`.